# Dart json.decode can't decode to Map<String, String>

Tags: json, dart

My code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

String jsonString = '''{
"a": "g",
"b": "h",
"c": "j",
"d": "k"
}''';

Map<String, String> map = json.decode(jsonString);
```

Getting the error:

```
Unhandled exception:
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'
#0      main (file:///...)
#1      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:298:32)
#2      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:171:12)
```

`Map<String, dynamic> map ...`
and `Map<String, Object> map ...` 
Are working.

I am trying to de serialize in the end `Map<String, Map>` for different JSON and it gave me the same error so I have decided to first work with the basic which is the `Map<String, String>` to better understand what am I doing wrong

Comment: Try `Map<String, String> data = Map.castFrom(json.decode(jsonString))`.
If this still fails check if all the values in your JSON data are of type String

Comment: This is working, can you post this as answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make sure the JSON is cast to the specified value use the [Map.castFrom](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/Map/castFrom.html) method.

So your code becomes

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main () {
  String jsonString = '''
{
  "a": "g",
  "b": "h",
  "c": "j",
  "d": "k"
}''';

  Map<String, String> map = Map.castFrom(json.decode(jsonString));
  print(map);
}
```

Note that if the types are incompatible it will throw. You should always consider handling that.

Answer (score 0):

when I worked with firebase messaging. I enforced to do like this receive body of the notification. I don't know the reason but I solve it like this:

```
Map<String, String> valueMap = Map.castFrom(json.decode(json.decode(payload!)));
```