# NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart

This is my error line:

[image: This is my error line]

here is my code:

[image: here is my code]

Comment: Please post your code in text form and not as an image!

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56916805/6891637)

Answer (score 1):

```
final jobs= json.decode(response.body)['name_database_table'];
```

Comment: Welcome to this community! While brevity is generally fine, please provide some context and explanation on why you think this answer would work and how users should implement it. You may wish to refer to the guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.